# Adonis-Js : Get a specifc number of Entities in relationship with another Entity

Tags: entity-relationship, query-builder, adonis.js, lucid

I need your help in Adonis-Js for loading an an entity with relationships. Here is my problem :

I have two entities :

- **Contact** (belongsTo Contactgroup)
- **Contactgroup** (hasMany Contact)

I want to make a request to get the list of **Contactgroup** with some **Contact** in it, here is an exemple, this code gives me all **Contactgroup** with all **Contact** related to them.  :

```
    let ContactgroupList = await Contactgroup.query()
        .where('profile_id', auth.user.id)
        .with('contact')
        .fetch();
```

In my case I just want to get all **Contactgroup** with only some **Contact** related to them (for exemple a maximum of 3 **Contact** for each **Contactgroup** found), but when I use the code below :

```
    let ContactgroupList = await Contactgroup.query()
        .where('profile_id', auth.user.id)
        .with('contact', (builder) => {
          builder.pick(3)
        })
        .fetch();
```

I get only the first 3 **contact** related to the first **Contactgroup**, exemple :

if **Contactgroup[0]** have X **Contact** -> it shows an array of the first 3 **contact** of it, and
if **Contactgroup[1]** have X **Contact** -> it will show an empty array.

How can I get 3 **contact** for each **Contactgroup** ?

I hope my explanation is clear, and thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a friend of mine gave me the solution with using the **eagerLoadQuery** :

```
let ContactgroupList = await Contactgroup.query()
  .where('profile_id', auth.user.id)
  .with('contact', (builder) => {
    builder.eagerLoadQuery((relationQuery, foriegnKey, groups) => {
      relationQuery
        .from('contacts as c')
        .whereRaw('(select count(*) from `contacts` as c1 where c.contactgroup_id = c1.contactgroup_id AND c.id < c1.id) < 3')
        .whereIn(`c.${foriegnKey}`, groups)
        .orderBy('c.id', 'desc')
    })
  })
  .fetch()
```

see also this post for more informations : [Link](https://forum.adonisjs.com/t/what-is-better-for-performance/460/9)